# EWMA Volatility vs Volatility of EWMA

Tags: time-series, garch

Is taking the standard deviation of a EWMA smoothed series equivalent to getting the EWMA volatility for that series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. if you take the standard deviation of a (smoothed) series you’ll be estimating a single sample standard deviation for the entire series. In contrast, the EWMA volatility estimates a conditional volatility for each period in the sample.